# How to substract ammount of characters from tweets

Tags: jquery, twitter, character

I have a twitter fetcher script and simply want to cut ammount of characters from tweets. I need to get output of Twitter fetcher, cut it and replace in HTML.

So here is my code:

```
var str = $("#tweets .tweet").each(function() { $(this).text(); });

$("#tweets .tweet").each(function() {
  $(this).html(str.substring(0, 50));
});
```

But I receive the error **Uncaught TypeError: str.substring is not a function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#tweets .tweet").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().substring(0, 50));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that works great. But now I'm having new problem that it returns text without any links. I'm trying to modify this pen - https://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype

Comment: @Alexander sweet!

Comment: Any idea how to use plain JS with innerText to apply it? Here is my pen - https://codepen.io/DeoThemes/pen/jyGPgr

Comment: Thanks again, but unfortunatelly the problem is still exist. It returns text without links. I got the reply from plugin developer: _I dont use jQuery but using raw JavaScript you can just get the innerText of the element that contains the tweet and then apply it to that_

Comment: You can't just cut off text if you want to preserve the HTML/links. You have to have a bunch of logic that makes sure you don't, for example, cut off text in the middle of a link and leave an open tag. Feel free to submit a new question since none of these details were in your original question.